# Setting up a server with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use this commmand:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

but it's not working. I'm guessing that it isn't working because I'm running that through Windows Command Prompt. How does one make that function?

The error I am getting from Command Prompt is: "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: You don't have python installed...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question might receive some downvotes because you fail to provide minimal understanding of the subject matter normally expected of an asker. Please [refer to the FAQ on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidelines for asking questions. In this case, the problem is that you need to install Python, and either put in in your system PATH, or run this command from the directory where Python is installed.

Comment: I do have Python installed though, I can open up its command line and everything. I tried running some simple commands through python like: 
print "hello" and it worked. 

How do you put python in your system PATH?

Comment: Never mind, I can google that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i think You need to add that folder to your Windows Path this link can be useful :

https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

[bluebird7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2867928/bluebird7) is right. You need to add python to your windows path. You can try this temporary alternative, type in cmd:

```
c:\python27\python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

The upper command will only work for python 2.7 and python needs to be installed here: `c:\python27`